# Exclusion Scripts for Opt-outs

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, exclusion-script

We have a custom preference center, with opt-out changes landing in a data extension. I would like to create an exclusion script for Journey Builder sends that takes into account the opt-outs from preference changes and/or general opt-out in real-time from the Master Permission data extension. The Master Permission DE has the following columns: Contact_Key (unique identifier for contacts & PrimaryKey), OptIn (boolean), OptIn_Electronic_Pricelist (boolean), OptIn_New_Launches (boolean).  For this use-case, I would need the exclusion script to check if a contact has OptIn_New_Launches = false AND OptIn = false

Here's the code I used from SF KnowledgeBase, but I don't know how to apply it to this situation:

```
ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("Master_Permission","Contact_Key", _subscriberkey))>0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Exclusionscript should probably be like this:

`ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("Master_Permission","Contact_Key", _subscriberkey, "OptIn_New_Launches",0,"OptIn",0))>0`

> 0 inside being effectively a "false" when i remember correctly, for your LookUp against the Columns "OptIn_New_Launches" and "Optin"

or

`ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("Master_Permission","Contact_Key", _subscriberkey, "OptIn_New_Launches",false,"OptIn",false))>0`

That should be your ExclusionScript. Test it though. You just needed to ask for two more conditions.

- [**LookUpRows** by Salesforce Developers Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuprows.htm)
- [**LookUpRows** by ampscript.guide](https://ampscript.guide/lookuprows/)